# Can not install "npm install -g botdispatch" on Azure app service on linux

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, npm-install, azure-linux

I was trying to install botdispatch npm module as a part of bot framework 4 on Azure app service on Linux and I get stuck with this error.

Here's the error that I get:

```
    root@1c46f16cd26b:/home/site/wwwroot# **npm install -g botdispatch**
    /usr/local/bin/dispatch -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/botdispatch/bin/dispatch.js

    > dotnet-2.1@2.1.1003 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/botdispatch/node_modules/dotnet-2.1
    > node -e "/*PostInstall: Installs platform-specific .NET framework */try{require('./dist/app.js')}catch(e){}"

    events.js:167
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

    Error: spawn /usr/local/bin/node EACCES
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    Emitted 'error' event at:
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:238:12)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! dotnet-2.1@2.1.1003 postinstall: `node -e "/*PostInstall: Installs platform-specific .NET framework */try{require('./dist/app.js')}catch(e){}"`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the dotnet-2.1@2.1.1003 postinstall script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-09-16T18_53_05_409Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

After removing the module and manually deleting "bot dispatcher" from global module folder and installing it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, this module requires .NET Core as a pre-requisite. Depending on which framework version you are using on App Service, you might need some modifications to your approach. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/botdispatch

Comment: I installed .Net Core 2.1 still getting same error